# Elasticsearch Java API migration form TermsFacetBuilder with AggregationBuilders

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am migrating from ES 1.7 to 5.2 and refactoring the following code.

ES 1.7

```
public void prepare(final SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder) {
        final TermsFacetBuilder labelsFacet = FacetBuilders
                .termsFacet("labels")
                .field("labels");
        searchRequestBuilder.addFacet(labelsFacet);
        searchRequestBuilder.setFrom(start);
        searchRequestBuilder.setSize(size);
    }
```

with ES 5.2

```
 public void prepare(final SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder) {
        TermsAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms("labels").field("labels");
        searchRequestBuilder.addAggregation(aggregation);
        searchRequestBuilder.setFrom(start);
        searchRequestBuilder.setSize(size);
    }
```

When I fire the search query I am getting the following exception

```
nested: IllegalArgumentException[Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [labels] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.]
```

I also tried setting the fieldDocValue on SearchRequestBuilder but no luck.

Comment: Did you `Set fielddata=true on [labels]`, as the error message said?

Comment: @Jeremy, How do we set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, you need to [enable `fielddata`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html) in your mapping.

For example, here is a new mapping using `fielddata=true` on a `text` field.

```
PUT my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
  "properties": {
    "my_field": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy. Actually, I wanted to set it using Java API. I tried searching on ES documentation but did not found one.